# I want to download a excel file through Checkbox Unique ID in laravel, I am using Maatwebsite\Excel Here

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, maatwebsite-excel

My Controller File

```
public function enquiryExport($id, Request $request)
{
    $id[] = $request->explode(",",$id);
    return Excel::download(new EnquiryExport($id), 'enquiry.xlsx');
}
```

and My Export File

```
 protected $id;
function __construct($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
 }

public function collection()
{
    return Enquiry::whereIn('id',explode(",",$this->id))->get();

   /* return Enquiry::all(); */
}
```

Route is like

```
 Route::get('enquiryExport', 'enquiryController@enquiryExport');
```

Still I am getting this error

```
"message": "Too few arguments to function App\\Http\\Controllers\\enquiryController::enquiryExport(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected",
```

I am checkbox id through AJAX here.

Comment: Your controller `enquiryExport($id, Request $request)` expects an `id`, your route `Route::get('enquiryExport', 'enquiryController@enquiryExport');` does not pass any id.

Comment: Either update your controller with default value `enquiryExport($id=null, Request $request)` or update your route with an `id` like, `Route::get('enquiryExport/{id}', 'enquiryController@enquiryExport');`

Comment: `Route::get('enquiryExport/{id}', 'enquiryController@enquiryExport');` accept id from route

Answer (score 0):

The problems is your `Route` method.

`Get` method: the query string (name/value pairs) is sent in the URL of a GET request

`Post` method: the data sent to the server with POST is stored in the request body of the HTTP request

If you use `Get` method: try this (I have just read it, not tried)

```
Route::get('enquiryExport/{id}', 'enquiryController@enquiryExport')->name('enquiryExport');

<a href="{{ route('enquiryExport', serialize($id)) }}">Submit</a>
```

If you use `Post` method: try this (I am used to use this)

```
Route::post('enquiryExport', 'enquiryController@enquiryExport');

public function enquiryExport(Request $request)
{
    return Excel::download(new EnquiryExport($request->input('id')), 'enquiry.xlsx');
}
```

You can read more here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try this
In controller:

```
   public function enquiryExport(Request $request, $id)
   {
     return Excel::download(new EnquiryExport($request->id), ''.date('Y-m-d'). '.xlsx', \Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::XLSX);
   }
```

In Export File:

```
       protected $id;

        function __construct($id) {
            $this->id = $id;
        }
       public function collection()
        {

          return Enquiry::where('id', $this->id)->get();
       }


       public function map($enquiry): array
{
    
    return [
        // $enquiry->WRITE YOUR RECORDS,
        // ...

    ];
}

public function headings(): array
{
    return [
            //NAME HEADINGS(TITLE) OF YOUR RECORDS IN SIDE SINGLE QUOTATION,
            // ...
    ];
}
```

In Route:

```
    Route::get('enquiryExport/{id}', 'enquiryController@enquiryExport');
```